# populate input field using javascript problem

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for the responses.. i put a live version of the code.. to see if that helps resolve this.  It is here:

http://www.zacharydesigns.com/sandbox/calculatorJS.html

I updated the following code to reflect what was offered as an answer.. however this just returns zero

I am having trouble wrapping my head around creating a simple equation in javaScript.  What I am trying to achieve is to have `a=(x/z)*y`.

```
x = user input
z = total of all input
y = defined number (in this case 300)
```

What I came up with is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function update()
{
    var a = $("#productOne").val(); // '#' identify IDs as in CSS
    var b = $("#productTwo").val();
    var c = $("#productThree").val();
    var productTotal = Math.floor(a/(a+b+c));
    $("#productTotal").val(productTotal); // Set calculated value in the HTML
}

</script>

<form name="calc" action="#">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
                <td align="right">
                        Product One:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="productOne" id="productOne" size="5" /></td>
                <td align="right">
                        Product Two:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="productTwo" id="productTwo" size="5" /></td>
                <td align="right">
                        Product Three:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="productThree" id="productThree" size="5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="update();return false;" />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <td align="right">
                Product Total:</td>
        <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="productTotal" id="productTotal" size="6" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr></table>
</form>
```

which I am not sure is even close.  Can someone help guide me through this, please?

Comment: where is your problem? with input what would you want as expected output?

Comment: As far as I've understood from the code he just wants to update a HTML input field with the calculated value from other inputs.

Comment: After applying some indentation, it is obvious that there is a `<tr>` tag missing.

Comment: @Gergely-well then the title needs to be editing-@zac- is Gergely right about thats what you're asking for?

Comment: hi yes sorry it is not clearer.. yes Gergely is correct I want to update that field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of things that are not working in your script:

- The `year` variable is not used and there is no `year` input in your form.
- The `a`, `b` and `c` variable declaration, I think that you want to get the values from your input elements.
- You assign the calculation to the `productTotal` variable, and later you use the undefined `theProductTotal` variable.

To get the form elements by `name` I would recommend you something like this:

```
function update() {
  var a = +document.forms['calc'].elements['productOne'].value,
      b = +document.forms['calc'].elements['productTwo'].value,
      c = +document.forms['calc'].elements['productThree'].value,
      productTotal = Math.floor(a/(a+b+c)*300);

  document.forms['calc'].elements['productTotal'].value = productTotal;

  return false;
}
```

Notice how I'm getting the input values, since you are using only the `name` attribute, you can access the elements in that way.

Also look that I'm converting the input values to Number (by using the unary plus operator), since the `value` property is string, and that can give you problems when you sum, because if you use the add operator with strings a concatenation will take place.

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/iloqo).

Answer (score 0):

Using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) a working code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function update() {

var a = parseInt($("#productOne")val()); // '#' identify IDs as in CSS
var b = parseInt($("#productTwo").val());
var c = parseInt($("#productThree").val());
var productTotal = Math.floor(a/(a+b+c)*300);


$("#productTotal").attr("value",productTotal); // Set calculated value in the HTML

} 
</script> 

<form name="calc" action="#">

<table align="center"
border="1"><tr><td align="right">Product One: </td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="productOne" id="productOne" size="5" />
</td>
<td align="right">Product Two: </td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="productTwo" id="productTwo" size="5" />
</td>
<td align="right">Product Three: </td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="productThree" id="productThree" size="5" />
</td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="button" value="Calculate"
onclick="update();return false;" /> </td></tr>

<td align="right">Product Total:</td><td align="left">
<input type="text" name="productTotal" id="productTotal" size="6"
readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
</table></form>
```

Hopefully I haven't missed anything.

Comment: You should convert the `a`, `b` and `c` variables to Number, otherwise the `(a+b+c)` expression will be evaluated as string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks Gergely... isnt working just returning zeros.. I put a live example here:
http://www.zacharydesigns.com/sandbox/calculatorJS.html

Comment: Corrected to parse the strings to integers. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Use .val() instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update()
{
    var a = parseInt($("#productOne").val()); // '#' identify IDs as in CSS
    var b = parseInt($("#productTwo").val());
    var c = parseInt($("#productThree").val());
    var productTotal = Math.floor(a/(a+b+c)*300);
    $("#productTotal").val(productTotal); // Set calculated value in the HTML
}

</script>

<form name="calc" action="#">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                Product One:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="productOne" id="productOne" size="5" /></td>
            <td align="right">
                Product Two:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="productTwo" id="productTwo" size="5" /></td>
            <td align="right">
                Product Three:
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="productThree" id="productThree" size="5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="update();return false;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td align="right">
            Product Total:</td>
        <td align="left">
            <input type="text" name="productTotal" id="productTotal" size="6" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks Eric... couldnt get that to work either.. i updated the code with your here:

http://www.zacharydesigns.com/sandbox/calculatorJS.html

Comment: `val()` is more correct than broken `attr()`, but this is still adding strings together not integers.